# Is "Last time we were in a house was five weeks" a common colloquialism?

Tags: word-meaning, adverbs, colloquial-language

There a scene in the movie [*Red Dawn*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Dawn):

A group of teenagers come to a house and are welcomed in by the owner.

> One of the teenagers: Last time we were in a house was five weeks.
>
> Man: You look it.

Is "Last time ... was five weeks", as opposed to "Last time we were in a house was five weeks **ago**." a common colloquialism? It seems to me the grammatical way to say it would be with the adverb **ago**.

Also I understand *look* in "You look it" to mean "to have the appearance of", as in "looks her age" ([MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/look)). But a search on Google Books seems to suggest this line is not very commonly used, as the majority of the hits are false positives, such as "Whenever you look, it is slightly different." Despite having found it in some books, I still wonder: is this expression common? I haven't found anything substantial, except [one WordReference thread](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/you-dont-look-it-so.2571080/). "You don't look it." sounds less odd than "You look it."

Comment: Please note: scriptwriters take liberties to create characters. Also, it implies ago. In fact in totally cleaned up English (which is not how teens talk), it would be: The last time were were in a house was five weeks ago. It is not a saying. A saying is a truism. This is like jazz: if you really want to understand jazz, first you learn  music theory. Language is the same: First you learn the standard way to say things and then you can move onto the jazz of language.

Comment: @Lambie Thanks for pointing out that mistake of mine! Born to American parents in a non-English speaking country, I consider myself a heritage speaker of English. Not sure if I can call English my first language, but it was the first language I ever learned to speak. I know I stumble over simple things from time to time, but I think I am ready to jazz, and it's jazz I am interested in.

Comment: **You look it** is perfectly idiomatic but **the last time ... was five weeks** is not idiomatic there.  It would be idiomatic if it were expressing a duration.  *She gets a recurrent rash that takes a long time to fade. The last time was five weeks.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to answer this other than it's not standard, and it's not something I remember anyone saying -- but the meaning is clear, so I wouldn't make a big deal of it.

It's like when someone says "You jerk!".  Proper grammar would be "You are a jerk!" but shortening it makes it more emphatic.

Alternately the writer could have purposefully mixed the phrases:

> It's been five weeks since we've been in a house.
>
> The last time we were in a house was five weeks ago.

in order to suggest the speaker (I assume Patrick Swayze's character) is particularly *tired* from their ordeal, and not thinking straight.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you! Just looking for testimony to the currency of a particular way of speaking in colloquial language, or the lack thereof. Any comment on "You look it."? I haven't found anything substantial, except [one WordReference thread](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/you-dont-look-it-so.2571080/). "You don't look it." sounds less odd than "You look it."

Comment: @EddieKal  *"You look it"* is fairly common.